# How can I list sbt dependecies?

Tags: sbt

I have tried with https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph
but I got this

```
 sbt dependencyTree
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/milenko/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Set current project to milenko (in build file:/home/milenko/)
[info] default:milenko_2.10:0.1-SNAPSHOT [S]
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 10/02/2017 15:00:55
```

Is there any other solution or something is wrong with my installation?

Comment: How does your project look like ? Could you share a link ?

Comment: could you share your global plugins.sbt and build.sbt?